# How to export an Adobe Flash cc file compatible with Flash Player 8?

Tags: flash, flash-cc

I have created several banners through Flash CC. However the ad server is only compatible with Flash version 8 and below. I would then like to know how to export the Flash CC files to make them compatible with Flash version 8, even if I have to rewrite the AS3 code to AS2.

I have read about adding the playerglobal.swc files however I have not been able to find the one corresponding to Flash Player 8.

Sorry if this question has already been asked but I am pretty stuck here.

Have a good evening.

Answer (score 2):

To answer to my question: There is no way to publish for Flash Player 8 through the lovely Flash CC.

To fix this you have to:

- Install Flash Professional CS6
- Export your animations from Flash CC
- Open them in CS6, change your actions to make them work with as2
- Publish for Flash Player 8

Thank you Adobe.

Answer (score -1):

Flash CC by default let's you target only Flash Player 10.3 and upwards.
However, there are workarounds to target older versions of Flash Player.

This forum discusses about it in detail - http://forums.adobe.com/message/5420549  (see post #15 by kglad)

Another post that pretty much sums it up - http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1397958

Comment: please provide a complete answer. Not only a link

Comment: Basically you are just confirming what the author has asked how to do as possible without telling how.

Comment: The forum posts i've provided, gives the exact solution to this question and also covers various doubts/clarifications people had while trying the steps. Do you think copy-pasting the same info will add any value?